# Организация приложения на стороне клиента

Tags: jquery, ajax, архитектура

На фронте использую JQuery. После ajax запроса приходится инициализировать заново обработчики событий. Подскажите как грамотно обходить или решать данную проблему? Наприме есть такой код:

```
$('.btn-change-status').on('click',function(){  
    $.post(url,function(data){
         $('.btn-change-status').on('click',function(){

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо вешать обработчик не на элемент а на `document`

`$(document).on('click', '.btn-change-status', function(){ ........ });`

http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On документация по методу `on`

Comment: А есть подробное описание почему надо на документ? И если много событий? Как правильно?

Comment: в двух словах, когда вы вешаете событие на document то оно применяется для динамично созданных элементов. вам надо почитать о делегировании событий, почитать внимательно https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: не обязательно вешать на document, можно например повесить на body или же просто на родителя того элемента с которым вы работаете

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-change-status', function(){
     $.post(url,function(data){
         // ваше действие
    }
})
```